# How do I convert an array of objects to an object of objects?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have the following array of objects:

```
[{id:1, name: Hana, age: 30}, {id:2, name: Sana, age: 20}, {id:3, name: Kana, age: 30}]
```

I want to convert it to an object of objects as following:

```
{0:{id:1, name: Hana, age: 30}, 1:{id:2, name: Sana, age: 20}, 2:{id:3, name: Kana, age: 30}}
```

Comment: It's pretty easy, have you tried anything?

Comment: Out of interest why do you want to do this? The array is already zero-indexed. This doesn't really seem to solve a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using Object's pre built method `assign` you can achieve this.

`Object.assign({}, yourObject);`

> ***No need to iterate through the Array unnecessary.***

Comment: FYI, this also iterates through the indices of the array internally.

Comment: Agree, but it will reduce the time complexity and with this we do not need to write custom logic for it.

Comment: where do I pass the array of objects here?

Comment: after the `,` i have mentioned it in answer as well by adding yourObject. You can assign that result to the any variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve the result, using a simple `map` function and store the result in an `object` as a `key:value` pair

```js
const data = [{id:1, name: 'Hana', age: 30}, {id:2, name: 'Sana', age: 20}, {id:3, name: 'Kana', age: 30}]

const resultObj = {}

data.map((obj,index) =>  resultObj[index] = obj)

console.log(resultObj)
```

Comment: Arrow functions should not return assignment, could you improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can map that array and get its unique value (in this case i have taken id as key) then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it according you want to display array.

Here is an example to do that.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Hana',
  age: 30
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Sana',
  age: 20
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Kana',
  age: 30
}]


var mapped = arr.map(item => ({
  [item.id]: item
}));
var newObj = Object.assign({}, ...mapped);
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: he/she is new so its hard for him to understand map/filter etc